# DeadObjectException on android app while integrating with Unity

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I integrate unity app with android.
From on button click I called my unity app. First time it run perfectly but when I run second time then I got DeadObjectException.

I used Application.Quit() in unity to come back from scene to android activity.

Below is my unity player activity  code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String imgPrevious = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Image");



        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(UnityPlayerActivity.this);

        setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
        try {
        System.loadLibrary("main"); // I believe just checks the default location

        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("SourceFace", "GetImage",imgPrevious);





    }
```

Below is android code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         fakeR = new FakeR(this);
        setContentView(fakeR.getId("layout","activity_main"));

        btnSelect = (ImageView) findViewById(fakeR.getId("id","btnSelectPhoto"));
        profilePic= getIntent().getExtras().getString("profileUrl");
    new ImageLoadTask().execute();

        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(fakeR.getId("id","ivImage"));
        btnNext = (Button)findViewById(fakeR.getId("id","btnNext"));

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                     String imageUrl= getIntent().getExtras().getString("templateUrl");
 String pic= getIntent().getExtras().getString("Pic");
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select image -> " + pic + " :-> " +Everyplay.isSupported(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);

                    i.putExtra("Image", profilePic);
                    i.putExtra("ImageURL", imageUrl);
                    startActivity(i);


            }
        });


    }
```

First time it runs fine. When I click on android button second time then it gives me.

> android.os.DeadObjectException

How can I resolve this issue.
Please help me.